# Can I save the Google Map API attributes for further search?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am selling stuff online and I would like to geocode my customer delivery addresses before delivery to make the delivery address is correct to avoid wrong delivery. If I use Google Map API, after I query an address, can I save the returned attribute in the own storage (such as building and street names, lat/lon) so that I don't need to re-query every time? Some customers addresses are repeating or written in incorrect format. If I can search it from my own archieve before Google Map API query, it can save the amount of time/queries required?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding

Answer (score 0):

The Terms of service allow a temporary caching up to 30 days with a purpose of improving the performance of your application. The permanent storage is prohibited.

For further details refer to section 10.5 of [Terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5):

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
>
> is secure;
>
> does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
>
> does not modify attribution in any way.